# Missing Select Keyword SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

```
PROMPT ' Data entry for the Publishers ' 

ACCEPT v_pub_id    varchar2(30)   FORMAT 'A10'         PROMPT 'Enter Publisher ID: '
ACCEPT v_pub_name  char   FORMAT 'A80'         PROMPT 'Enter Publisher Name: '
ACCEPT v_pubdate   date   FORMAT 'dd/mm/yyyy'  PROMPT 'Enter the pulication date(dd/mm/yyyy):' 

INSERT INTO PUBLISHERS
('&v_pub_id','&v_pub_name','&v_pubdate');
```

I not sure what is missing in the statement.

Comment: another problem here ' Data entry for the Publishers ' SP2-0003: Ill-formed ACCEPT command starting as varchar2(30) FORMAT 'A10' PROMPT 'Enter Publisher ID: ' Enter Publisher Name: ttttt Enter the pulication date(dd/mm/yyyy):11/11/2015 Enter value for v_pub_id: T1001

Answer (score 1):

Although your specific syntax error is the missing `VALUES` keyword, you should always include the list of columns in an `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO PUBLISHERS(pub_id, pub_name, pubdate)
    VALUES ('&v_pub_id','&v_pub_name','&v_pubdate');
```

If the table format changes, then the statement will start generating errors.  Furthermore, it will not be clear to another person (or to you in two weeks), what variables are being assigned to which columns.  Be explicit and avoid future errors.

Comment: another problem here                                                                                     ' Data entry for the Publishers ' SP2-0003: Ill-formed ACCEPT command starting as varchar2(30) FORMAT 'A10' PROMPT 'Enter Publisher ID: '                                                                                             Enter Publisher Name: ttttt Enter the pulication date(dd/mm/yyyy):11/11/2015                                                           Enter value for v_pub_id: T1001                                                                  not enough value for line 1

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `values` keyword before the list of values:

```
INSERT INTO PUBLISHERS
VALUES ('&v_pub_id', '&v_pub_name', '&v_pubdate');
```

Comment: Thank for the answer , but now he pop out * not enough value

Comment: and another problem ' Data entry for the Publishers '
SP2-0003: Ill-formed ACCEPT command starting as varchar2(30)   FORMAT 'A10'       PROMPT 'Enter Publisher ID: '
Enter Publisher Name: ttttt
Enter the pulication date(dd/mm/yyyy):11/11/2015
Enter value for v_pub_id: T1001